# How we can access a localhost of a computer through its public IP if some other devices in the same network also have the same public IP?

Tags: networking, tcp

I want to access localhost of a computer but other computers in the same network also has the same public IP. Can we access its localhost host by knowing both(public and private) IP address of that computer. I want to connect to it directly(not through any software like ngrok or VPN).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They don't. They are all behind a NAT device that has that IP address. You have to arrange appropriate and unambiguous port forwarding at the NAT device. Off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access *localhost* on the computer itself. *Localhost* refers to 'this node' by definition.

When communicating on an internal network you usually use the private IP addresses, not the public one(s). Connecting to a computer with a private IP behind a public IP requires reverse NAT aka destination NAT aka port mapping.

Connecting out from and right back into the same network through NAT may require a special firewall setup aka hairpinning. It's usually easier and faster to use split-brain DNS and resolve the public name to the private IP address of the device.